# Integer solutions of : $u+pv=(x+py)(z+pt)$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $u,v$ be integers. Then, there exist integers $x,y,z,t$ such that 
$$u+pv=(x+py)(z+pt)$$
How can I find all integers $x,y,z,t$ knowing $u,v$?
What I have done:
$$p^2(yt)+p(yz+xt-v)+xz-u=0$$
If $yt=0$ then it's trivial. So I suppose that $yt\neq 0$
We have a quadratic equation in $p$
hence
$$(yz+xt-v)^2-4yt(xz-u)=r^2$$ where $r $ is an integer.
$$(yz+xt)^2-2v(yz+xt)+y^2-4yt(xz-u)=r^2$$
$$(yz-xt)^2-2v(yz+xt)+y^2+4ytu=r^2$$
Which did not get me too far. Any hints?

Comment: I think you need to establish some condition like $xz\equiv u\pmod p$, then you can divide through by $p$ and proceed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found it.
The above equation yields $2$ odd primes $p,q$. Then, it is easy to show that:
$$zx-u=pqyt$$
$$v-xt-yz=(p+q)yt$$
Then
$$u=zx-pqyt$$
$$v=(p+q)yt+xt+yz$$
It follows that:
$$(zx-pqyt)+p[yt(p+q)+xt+yz]=(x+py)(z+pt)$$